# Vectorize the following for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization, cell-array

```
i = [1 2 3 4 5];
a = {[1 3 4 5] [5 4 3] [1 2 3] [4] [5 2]};
b = {[1] [4 2 3] [1 3] [2 1 4] [1 2 3]};
```

For `a`and `b` the following conditions hold

1. Cell arrays `a`and`b`are of the size of `i`
2. Each element in each array of `a`and `b` are from the elements of `i`

Is there any way to Vectorise the following code to avoid `for` loop

```
x = 0;
for elem = i
    x = x + sum(ismember(cell2mat(a(a{elem})),b{elem}));
end
x
```

Thanks

Comment: It's always useful to provide (a) the output `x` and (b) an explanation of what your loop is doing

Comment: I highly doubt you can fully vectorize this. Maybe if you padded all the inner vectors to be the same size (but you won't be able to vectorize that...). Is this really too slow though? If so, have you tried using the profiler to find potential bottlenecks?

Comment: @Dan I can't say that it is too slow but I saw somewhere that matlab is slow with for loop and it's better to vectorise it (if possible). Also, the one above is just an example, in my work I have to deal with large vectors.

Comment: MATLAB for loops have not been slow for years now. What you are doing is text-book premature optimization. If you spend more time trying to optimize your code for speed than you gain from the optimization, then it is far from optimal. First run the code on actual data, then decide if you need to optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

The way I see it as, you would have a bottleneck with the `cell2mat` inside the loop. If you are running it for considerable number of loop iterations, this bottleneck would be felt. So, with this post I would try to re-organize the input array `a` so that the `cell2mat` would be used on it once outside the loop. That would be used to extract all elements and then re-group cell elements into another cell array, whose each cell would hold values corresponding to the `cell2mat()` extracted values at each iterations with the original code. Thus, each cell of such a re-organized cell array could be fed directly to replace `cell2mat(a(a{elem}))`.

So, to fulfil all of those promises, an implementation would be -

```
% Re-organize a to create another cell array in which each cell
% would have "cell2mat(a(a{elem}))" for iterator elem
lens = cellfun('length',a)
arr = [a{:}]
cumlens = cumsum(lens(arr))
grouped_cumlens = cumlens(cumsum(lens))
grouped_a = mat2cell(cell2mat(a(arr)),1,diff([0 grouped_cumlens]))

% Use grouped_a to perform the same operations but without cell2mat in loops
outx = 0;
for elem = i
    outx = outx + sum(ismember(grouped_a{elem},b{elem}));
end
```

If you are desperate for fully vectorized code, the loopy code is easily vectorizable with `bsxfun`, but I am not sure if that would provide performance benefit as it would depend on the data format you have for the inputs.

---

**Approach #2**

Here's an alternative approach that still persists with the previous version on extracting elements from `a`. But, instead of storing as another cell array, it keeps the regular array and additionally saves the start and stop indices corresponding to the limits used to extract elements from it at each iteration. Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
% Code un-changed from the previous version
lens = cellfun('length',a)
arr = [a{:}]
cumlens = cumsum(lens(arr))
grouped_cumlens = cumlens(cumsum(lens))

% Extract data into a regular array and decide start and stop indices
data = cell2mat(a(arr))
starts = [1 grouped_cumlens(1:end-1)+1]
stops = grouped_cumlens

% Use extracted data with its start,stop indices for each iteration
outx = 0;
for elem = i
    outx = outx + sum(ismember(data(starts(elem):stops(elem)),b{elem}));
end
```

Again `bsxfun` could be used with this version to fully vectorize things here!

Comment: Thank you, it is perfect and faster. Can you add some explanation to Approach #1 please.

Comment: @akki Sorry that's the best I could do. For more info refer to the docs for `cell2mat` and `mat2cell`.